# Как зарезервировать память для MapViewOfFileEx?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Работая с мапингом под виндой, столкнулся с такой проблемой, не получается зарезервировать буфер под [MapViewOfFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366763(v=vs.85).aspx).

При работе с файлом, как я понимаю, используется DMA, DMA позволяет ускорить обращение к памяти, если делается "выровняное" обращение. Если вызвать функцию с NULL указателем, то Windows сама определит место для мапинга, калькуляция занимает время... но... всётаки, можно ли "зараннее" зарезервировать место для мапинга? И быть уверенным, что окно всегда есть, и его никто "не украдёт" (что будет свободный линейный кусок на 64к)? Вот [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/861993/17974) реализовал я "повторный" мапинг. Если я подсовываю буфер, который зарезервировал с помощью VirtualAlloc MEM_RESERVE или MEM_RESERVE + MEM_COMMIT, то MapViewOfFileEx даёт ошибку

> ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS 487 (0x1E7) Attempt to access invalid address.

Пример (грубо)

```
DWORD AllocationGranularity = 65536;
void * mWnd = VirtualAlloc(0,AllocationGranularity , MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
VirtualAlloc(mWnd,AllocationGranularity , MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
void * wnd = MapViewOfFileEx(hMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0,0     AllocationGranularity,mWnd);
```

Или... можно использовать повторно то же место куда винда его определила, а если это место станет занятым, то сбрасывать указатель в ноль, и повторно вызывать `MapViewOfFileEx` с нулём? (Но тут есть вероятность, что свободной памяти может не оказаться)

Возможно есть другое хорошее решение?

Comment: Непонятно, чего именно вы собираетесь добиться: застолбить память или предотвратить изменение адреса про последующих маппингах. Первое на самом деле тут вообще не применимо, памяти может не оказаться даже после успешного создания оверлея. Второе непонятно зачем может понадобиться.

Comment: Не совсем ясно, а зачем здесь файл-маппинг? Вы резервируете весь диапазон, потом коммитите какое-то окно, а потом вызываете decommit

Comment: @VTT застолбить адрес(виртуальную память) и предотвратить изменение адреса про последующих маппингах. Поскольку виртуальная память не равна физической, застолбить кусок  что б мапинг использовал один кусок виртуальной памяти (как при работе с DMA). *За чем понадобится* - что б не заставлять винду искать "новое место" для мапинга.

Comment: А вы уверены что поиск "нового места" является потенциально проблемным местом вашего приложения? Как вы это определили? По мне, так лучше заняться чем-то более полезным.

Answer (score -1):

Все делается с точностью до наоборот. Вначале мапится регион с флагом `SEC_RESERVE`, а потом этому региону делается `MEM_COMMIT`

```
DWORD AllocationGranularity = 65536;
HANDLE hMap = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE | SEC_RESERVE,
  0, AllocationGranularity, NULL);
void * wnd = MapViewOfFileEx(hMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, AllocationGranularity, NULL);
void * mWnd = VirtualAlloc(wnd, AllocationGranularity, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

Проверка и обработка ошибок по вкусу

Ну и не забываем про страницы и гранулы

Comment: После MapViewOfFile commit делать не нужно. Да и в целом это ответ не на тот вопрос.

Comment: @freim коммит делать нужно, так как этот диапазон был только зарезервирован (флаг `SEC_RESERVE`).

Comment: `PAGE_READWRITE or SEC_RESERVE` должно быть `PAGE_READWRITE bitor SEC_RESERVE`, но вообще да, это не ответ на вопрос