# Доступ свыше 4GB памяти windows из под 32-битного приложения

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Как получить доступ к всей памяти не используя файл подкачки? Если он нужен - при работе с оперативной памятью - система сама этим займётся. Я вижу два способа, AWE и "interprocess".

Можно ли функцию `AllocateUserPhysicalPages` заставить работать на обычных компьютерах?
В Win10 эта функция тоже не работает?

Пример использования находится на сайте microsoft http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/awe-example

У меня на win7 x64 пример микрософта в x86 программе заканчивается ошибкой `Cannot enable the SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME privilege`.
Все хорошо, только функция памяти требует привелегий? Это как?
Т.е. 32-битное приложение не может использовать памяти более 4Гб через AWE окно, зато 64-битное может сьесть всю память?
Есть ли другие способы работать из 32-битного приложения с всей памятью? (Совет - запустите из-под админа не подходит, если мы пишем какую бы то ни было утилиту, утилиты-же вроде блокнота паинта или другого редактора - не клянчат админские привелегии)

Mozilla-Firefox, например одно время плодил процессы, мне приходила идея плодить процессы для доступа к памяти больше чем 4GB, т.е. единственный выход - плодить процессы (interprocess)? (Имеется ввиду: создаём ещё один процесс, там делаем Alloc памяти, а эту дополнительную память читаем через `ReadProcessMemory`, или если запрещено привелегиями то через Pipe).

Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, как она у вас решена?

Comment: Visual Studio до сих пор 32-битная. Многочисленным дополнениям для неё памяти катастрофически не хватает. Поэтому, в частности, Resharper был вынесен в отдельный процесс и общение реализовано с помощью IPC. Раз они не нашли лучшего способа, значит его и нет.

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Windowing_Extensions

Comment: Использование AWE должно быть заложено в код приложения. Также приложение должно иметь права «Lock Pages in Memory» (блокирование фрагмента памяти от выгрузки) для использования AWE.

Answer (score 0):

32-битная система, которая не сервер, не получает в принципе доступ к больше чем 4 ГБ физической памяти - см [Physical Memory Limits: Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#physical-memory-limits-windows-10)¹.

Соотвественно, получение бо́льшего объёма памяти будет связано с работой в 64-разрядной системой.

Для работы с большим объёмом памяти в 64-разрядной системе проще всего собирать 64-разрядные приложения.

---

¹ Возможно, это ограничение можно как-то обойти, но даже если и можно, это будет нарушать лицензию (как и включение функции `AllocateUserPhysicalPages` там, где она не должна работать).

Answer (score 0):

32-битное приложение может нарезервировать памяти свыше 4 GB посредством [`CreateFileMapping`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga) API и управлять всем этим "сверхквотным" объёмом. Что невозможно сделать так это одновременно весь этот объём памяти сделать адресно-доступным приложению посредством [`MapViewOfView`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile): приложение сможет сделать видимым себе лишь до 4 GB (в максимальном случае) одновременно. Тем не менее можно выборочно убирать какие-то фрагменты ([`UnmapViewOfFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-unmapviewoffile)) и вместо этого добавлять новые.

> [The most important part made so obvious is that the 32-bit application succeeds in allocating well over 4 GB, which is maximal virtual address space it can ever get.](https://alax.info/blog/1325)

Там же есть [prebuilt binary](https://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/FileMappingVirtualAddress/Win32/Release%20with%20Large%20Address%20Aware/FileMappingVirtualAddress.exe) поиграться.